# IIS request with quick response but continue to process

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on an API (Pragmatic Rest API or very similar). I would like to know if it is possible to do an API request that will return a quick response (in JSON) and continue to process heavy code in background.

I suppose this is possible by using queue system but I have no idea where to start with this.

Comment: If it is .Net Core, take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks), otherwise look at [this](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx). Both links describe a way to push work on a queue that is processed in the background. Using a queue won't spin up a process for each request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your API delegate long running things to another process.

You mentioned queues, that's one way of doing things, all you need really is an application which can execute whatever long running tasks you have.

Let's imagine a simple system that can do this.

Your API receives a request to do something.

Instead of doing this something, the API writes one record into a database with the details of what needs to be done. Another app watches that table, sees a new record, runs the thing, updates the record with the status / result / whatever it needs.

On any requests from now on, the API can check the record and return whatever is there.

This is the simplest thing I can think of. You can easily do other things as well, talk to a queue system, send it data, let something else execute it.

Looking at your comments, what you are suggesting is not really a good way of building APIs. Why do I say this? 
Well, let's say that you receive a request, the API starts a work thread and sends back a 200 to the client. Great the client knows work has started and how does it know when that process had ended and how does it receive whatever data it expects back?

Let's go a bit deeper next.

What happens when 1000 clients call that one endpoint and your API is attempting to start 1000 work threads? You've killed your API, no work gets done and no client gets anything.

This is why I suggest to delegate the work to something else, not the API. Let the API do what it does best, run quick things and return results and delegate other things to something else.

Comment: I could do that... of course... but this is not my question. Well this is a good first answer but I also want to know something in all this process. Is it possible I return a response from my API and continue a process or the response will also stop all process?

Comment: Example. I get a request. I create another thread that loop to infinity. When response is send back what happens to my another thread?

Comment: added more to my answer

Comment: Agreed, delegating to a queue is an optimal approach. I would use a 201 (created) or a 202 (accepted) instead of a 200 (ok). It's better because instead of implementing a less-than-discoverable behavior of having the same endpoint double as a status polling endpoint, you simply return the URL that you want the client to poll for status in the headers.

Comment: that was just an example, the real questions are those related to how you deal with the response and what do you do when the API has died because too many work threads are created. Those are the challenges not the choice between 200 and 201

Comment: that said, we both touched on but didn't explicitly mention the topic of re-entrancy

Comment: No no no. The process for the user has ended. If I continue something after the response it is not something the user is waiting for. I return a 200 and this is a 200. Let's says I continue the process for logging, performance checking and stuff like that. Stuff that are not part of the main process.

Comment: okay so you have asynchronous web api controller methods that define and start Task(s) for these "other" things before returning a Task with your 200 result to the caller